# Xamarin Forms Top of ListView Hides in MasterDetailPage

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making an App using Xamarin.Forms and on my iOS version, I'm having a really weird behavior with my `Listview` in the `Detail` portion of my main `MasterDetailPage`.  My app starts by setting the `MainPage` to my own `MasterDetailPage`:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainMasterDetailPage())
{
      Title = "App"
};
```

My `MainMasterDetailPage` is set up like this:

```
public partial class MainMasterDetailPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MainMasterDetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Detail = new HomePage()
        Master = new MenuPage()
    }
}
```

My `HomePage` has a vertical `StackLayout` with a `Button`, followed by a `ListView` and then another `Button` at the bottom of the page.  The problem is that when my `HomePage` is called on the iOS version of my app as the `Detail`, then the top heading of my `ListView` positions itself underneath (covered by) the button (the button is in the correct position right below the Navigation Bar).  In order to see the heading, I have to pull up on the `ListView` but when I release, it slides back under the button.  If I remove the button, it has the same behavior but it is covered instead by the `Navigation Bar`.

I know this is a problem with the `MasterDetailPage` because I changed one of my buttons to navigate to a new instance of `HomePage` and this one was set up correctly.

Is there something I did wrong or is this a bug with Xamarin?  Are there any quick fixes for me to work around it?

Comment: Your MasterDetail should be the root page of your app, not contained within a NavigationPage.

Comment: I tried setting my MainPage to my `MainMasterDetailPage` and then setting the detail to `new NavigationPage(new HomePage())` but the problem is still the same.  Also, then the navigation bar is missing from the `MenuPage` which doesn't look very good.  Is there a way to still have the bar if you set up a `MasterDetailPage` this way?

Comment: Another issue with setting it up this way is you can't call `Navigation.PushAsync()` from the `MasterPage`

Comment: The Master and Detail can each have their own Nav page

Comment: Yes but then the pages you navigate to from the Master only take up 2/3 of the screen which also isn't very visually appealing.  Is there a way for the navigation from the Master to take up the whole width of the screen?

Comment: Either way I have the same problem the question is about

Comment: It would help if you posted a screenshot of the behavior you're seeing, as well as the code/xaml for the page that has the problem.